# Superview that passes touch event to all it's subviews

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say we have following structure:

```
ParentViewController
    AChildViewController
    BChildViewController
    CChildViewController
```

All child view controllers fill completely the view of parent view controller. `AChildViewController` is at the bottom, and `CChildViewController` is at the top. If I make no change to the implementation, all touch events will be intercepted by `CChildViewController`. I can set `view.isUserInteractionEnabled` in `CChildViewController`, then `BChildViewController` will receive all the touch events. But my goal is that all of the child view controllers could handle the touch events, even they fill the same space and the are on top of each other. How can I do that assuming that I can change view implementations by overriding `loadView()` method in all of the view controllers?

Comment: What do you really want to do? If you simply want a function to be called in each child VC, then disable UserInteraction on the child views and call your own function on each child controller.

Comment: I have many gesture recognizers on child view controllers, so I'm looking for a function like `hitTest` or `point(inside:)` modification that would allow me to make these recognizers working.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate a bit. There are various approaches, but thinking about this in the abstract - many gesture recognizers doing what? - makes it difficult to offer a practical solution. Maybe distill it down to a couple specifics...